# iphone join network without internet

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, internet

i’m trying to join a network that’s intentionally not connected to the internet but on my iphone the wifi settings show the wifi symbol with an exclamation mark and ‘No Internet Connection’ in orange.

I remember this being a problem a few years ago but I thought this was resolved as iOS would typically ask you if you wanted to join the network without internet or choose another network, however this isn’t happening for me anymore.

I’ve tried to Reset Network Settings, configuring a fixed IP, and turning off Wifi assist as suggested on other threads.

I’m on iOS 14.6 on an iPhone 12 Pro

[image]

Comment: That looks as though it is connected to the network, otherwise it shouldn't know that the network has no internet connection.

Comment: I wish that was the case but it acts as if i'm not connected to a the network. this is confirmed by there being no wifi symbol at the top of the screen left of the battery symbol, and no access to any other devices on the network.

Comment: what info it shows when you click on ⓘ ?

Comment: @HarryBennett-Snewin no access to any other devices on the network isn't necessarily proof of it not being connected to the network. Please add the info shown in the ⓘ dialogue box as asked by Andra, as well as the IP address + subnet settings of some other devices on the network and the method of accessing them from your phone eg. are these web servers you're viewing through chrome? Please confirm that a different device such as a PC can access these other network devices via the same wifi access point as is used by your phone.

Comment: The network consists of a router at 192.168.12.1, 2 x devices that are addressed using dhcp and 2 APs that are also addressed using dhcp. My mbp can join the network with or without a static address and access the other devices but not my iphone. Unfortunately i’m not able to check the ⓘ right now as I won’t be with the kit now for another week. I’ll report back then